# Best way to render the children twice in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, react-hooks

To make an infinite slider I needed to use the same data twice.

The data is just an array within component with max 20 items, each one with image. The slider is working perfectly.

Yeah, its unusual, but needed on a simple application... what is the best or prettier way/practice to render this data without problems or performance loss if it exists?

```
function Page() {
  const data = [
  {
    src: "ObjectA"
  },
  {
    src: "ObjectB"
  },
  {
    src: "ObjectC"
  }
  ...
 ]

return (
  <Slider>
   {
     data.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <Component key={i}>
          <Child src={item.src}/>
        </Component>
      )
     })
   }
  </Slider>
 )
}
```

```
export default function Component(props: {children: ReactNode}) {
  return (
   {props.children}
  )
}
```

```
export default function Child(props: {src: string | StaticImport}) {
  return (
   <Image src={props.src} alt="..."/>
  )
}
```

**Some different approaches that work:**

```
export default function Component(props: {children: ReactNode}) {
  return (
   {props.children}
   {props.children}
  )
}
```

```
export default function Component(props: {children: ReactNode}) {
  const [childrenCopy] = useState(props.children) // really necessary?
  return (
   {props.children}
   {childrenCopy}
  )
}
```

```
function Page() {
  const data = [
  {
    src: "ObjectA"
  },
  {
    src: "ObjectB"
  },
  {
    src: "ObjectC"
  }
 ]

// no savings for code
return (
  <Slider>
   {
     data.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <Component key={i}>
          <Child src={item.src}/>
        </Component>
      )
     })
   }
   {
     data.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <Component key={i}>
          <Child src={item.src}/>
        </Component>
      )
     })
    }
  </Slider>
 )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use The Spread Operator (...). Learn more about this [here](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_spread_operator.asp)

```
function Page() {

const data = [
  {
    src: "ObjectA"
  },
  {
    src: "ObjectB"
  },
  {
    src: "ObjectC"
  }
  ...
 ]
const data2 = [...data, ...data]

return (
  <Slider>
   {
     data2.map((item, i) => {
      return (
        <Component key={i}>
          <Child src={item.src}/>
        </Component>
      )
     })
   }
  </Slider>
 )
}
```

Comment: That's a real good one. Maybe we can bring more opinions.